# Boxplots with Seaborn for all variables in a dataset at once

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, iris-dataset

I watched many videos, read the Seaborn documentation, checked many websites,  but I still haven't found the answer to a question.

This is from the Seaborn documentation:

```
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
ax = sns.boxplot(data=iris, orient="h", palette="Set2")
```

This code creates boxplots for each numerical variable in a single graph.

[image: Boxplots for Iris dataset]

When I tried to add the hue= "species", ValueError: Cannot use `hue` without `x` and `y`.  Is there a way to do this with Seaborn? I want to see Boxplots of all the numerical variables and explore a categorical variable.  So the graph will show all numerical variables for each species. Since there are 3 species, the total of Boxplots will be 12 (3 species times 4 numerical variables).

I am learning about EDA (exploratory data analysis). I think the above graph will help me explore many variables at once.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To apply "hue", seaborn needs the dataframe in ["long" form](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data). [`df.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) is a pandas function that can help here. It converts the numeric columns into 2 new columns: one called "variable" with the old name of the column, and one called "value" with the values. The resulting dataframe will be 4 times as long so that "value" can be used for `x=`, and "variable" for `y=`.

The long form looks like:

|  | species | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | setosa | sepal_length | 5.1 |
| 1 | setosa | sepal_length | 4.9 |
| 2 | setosa | sepal_length | 4.7 |
| 3 | setosa | sepal_length | 4.6 |
| 4 | setosa | sepal_length | 5.0 |
|  | ... | ... | ... |

```py
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
iris_long = iris.melt(id_vars=['species'])
ax = sns.boxplot(data=iris_long, x="value", y="variable", orient="h", palette="Set2", hue="species")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: boxplot with hue]

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. I will study the long form and the function pd.melt.